# Do not have function of get_Item() in office COM

Tags: c#

I am program to insert a excel sheet object to word specify location according to bookmark.Using COM.

The problem is:**not have a get_Item function**

This is my code:

```
public void writeExcelToWord(string fileName)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = null;
            Document doc= openWord(fileName, ref wordDoc, ref wordApp);

            object bookMark = "c";
            if (wordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("C") == true)
            {
                //doc.Bookmarks         //not have a get_Item function
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Info("Not define the bookmark...");
            }
        }
```

My referece code is searching from internet,this is the internet code:

```
       object bkmC = "C";
       if (wApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("C") == true)
       {
           wApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bkmC).Select();
       }
```

My office version is : 2010

My reference dll is:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll  14.0.0.0
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll   14.0.0.0
```

Comment: try `wordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.get_Item(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
wordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bkmC).Select();
```

Answer (score 0):

Few characters shorter:

```
wordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks[ref bkmC].Select();
```